# Can't log my t setAccessToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, unrecognized-selector

I want to make a new object from string access_token.
I've made a Token:NSObject (.h + .m) and I'm trying to setAccessToken and show it in the NSLog. This is the code in my LoginViewController.m:

```
NSString *token = responseObject[@"access_token"];

        Token *t = [[Token alloc]init];
        [t setAccessToken:token];
        NSLog(t);
```

And this is the error i get:

> Create[29485:770358] -[Token _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7f8e815d0780 
>   Create[29485:770358] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Token _fastCStringContents:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8e815d0780'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010149ff45 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000100f19deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001014a856d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013f5eea
>   ___forwarding_** + 970    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013f5a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5
>   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00000001036e8327
>   os_log_shim_with_CFString + 120   6   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010148ef24 _CFLogvEx3 + 132   7   Foundation
>   0x0000000100b9489e _NSLogv + 117  8   Foundation
>   0x0000000100ae40f2 NSLog + 152    9   Create
>   0x00000001004d665b **21-[LoginVC UserLogin:]_block_invoke + 203   10 
>   Create                              0x00000001004d7f18
>   __64-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke49 + 40  11 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001033fde5d
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010341e49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8     13  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001034062af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738   14 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001014002e9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013c18a9 __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2073    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013c0e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488   17  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001056dcad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  18  UIKit
>   0x000000010184c30d UIApplicationMain + 171    19  Create
>   0x00000001004d6a2f main + 111     20  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010345292d start + 1  21  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Hope somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog(...)` function assumes the first argument is an instance of `NSString`. If you want to use a different object, either use:

`NSLog([t description])` or a format string `NSLog(@"%@", t)`.

Comment: Okay! But I do that now, and it gives me:
<Token: 0x7f85e9cad610> 
:(

Comment: @MarckKühme That's absolutely correct behavior. What do you expect the result to be? How did you implement `Token`?

Comment: I thought it would log the access_token.. Implement? I have imported Token.h with some properties.

Comment: @MarckKühme Why don't you just log `token` instead of `t`? Or probably you can use something like `t.accessToken`. If class `Token` doesn't override `description`, logging will show only it's pointer value.